# Small Question regarding contour integration of $\int_{1=|z-i|} \frac {1}{z^2+1}dz$

Tags: contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am not certain if my Process of using Cauchy's Theorem is sound.
$$
\int_{1=|z-i|} \frac {1}{z^2+1}dz = \int_{1=|z-i|} \frac {1}{(z-i)(z+i)}dz = \int_{1=|z-i|} \frac {\frac {1}{z-1}}{(z+i)}dz 
$$
Now I can use Cauchy's Theorem and get
$$
= 2 \pi i * \frac{1}{2i} = -\pi
$$

Similarly i get the $\int_{1=|z-i|} \frac {1}{z^2+1}dz =\pi$

Is my process correct?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Did you mean to write $z^2+1$ instead of $z^1+1$?

Comment: Thx. I meant to write $z^2+1$. I edited the question just now.

Comment: in the second equality, is there a typo?

Comment: yes, i edited that, too. Thanks. Beware my result is wrong. Mark Viola provided a correction down below.

Comment: @Pascal it's stille wrong, it should be $z-i$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(z)=\frac1{z^2+1}$ has simple poles at $z=i$ and $z=-i$.  The pole at $z=-i$ is not enclosed by the contour $|z-i|=1$. Only the pole at $z=i$ is enclosed.

Hence, we have from Cauchy's Integral Formula

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z-i|=1}\frac1{z^2+1}\,dz&=\oint_{|z-i|=1}\frac{\frac1{z+i}}{z-i}\,dz\\\\
&=2\pi i \frac{1}{i+i}\\\\
&=\pi
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. That's what i tought when i altered the equation. i didnt realize that $(z+i)$ would represent the pole at $-i$ but at $i$. A careless mistake. Thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.